# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression after jQuery upgrade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After upgrading my jQuery version, this issue appears. After hours of work (there were lot of jquery files ) i finally found from is is this issue raising - because in console its pointing me toward actual file just pointing to jQuery file.

Here is what in my console shows :

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .menu-item > a[href*=#], .porto-sticky-nav .nav > li > a[href*=#], a[href^=#].hash-scroll, .hash-scroll-wrap a[href^=#]
```

This is triggering from this code :

```
$('.menu-item > a[href*=#], .porto-sticky-nav .nav > li > a[href*=#], a[href^=#].hash-scroll, .hash-scroll-wrap a[href^=#]').on('click', function(e) {
    // My code goes here...
    });
```

Can any one let me know what's i am doing wrong?

Comment: Which versions of jQuery did you upgrade from and to?

Comment: I am using jQuery v1.12.3 now.

Comment: Try quoting the attribute values – `a[href*="#"]`, etc. Unless the value is a valid identifier, which `#` isn't, [it should be quoted](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).

Comment: Awesome!! Wana hug you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add quotes to `#`.
change `#` to `"#"`

```
$('.menu-item > a[href*="#"], .porto-sticky-nav .nav > li > a[href*="#"], a[href^="#"].hash-scroll, .hash-scroll-wrap a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
  // My code goes here...
});
```